# Using VBA in Excel to Google Search in IE and return the hyperlink of the first result

Tags: excel, vba, msxml

I have been attempting to use IE automation to google search a string of text in Excel. I want to return the hyperlink for the website of the first result in another cell in excel. Is this possible? I have a list of 60,000 records that I need to google search and return the hyperlink for the website in the first result. Is there another approach to this that you would reccomend? I appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As its 60,000 records i recommend use xmlHTTP object instead of using IE.
HTTP requests a easier, and a lot faster

[Download the sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15vv4bi1k4g7n2OJ5wbjTVG_7ibxprLz6/view?usp=sharing)

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("h3")


        For Each link In objH3

            If link.className = "r" Then

                Cells(i, 2) = link.innerText
                Cells(i, 3) = link.getelementsbytagname("a")(0).href
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time) & " :minutes"
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

---

**Using CSS3 Selector**

```
 Sub XMLHTTP1()

        Dim url As String, i As Long, lastRow As Long
        Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As New HTMLDocument, objResultDiv As HTMLAnchorElement


        lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow

            url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

            Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
            XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
            XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
            XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
            XMLHTTP.send

            Set html = New HTMLDocument
            html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
            Set objResultDiv = html.querySelector("div#rso h3.r a")

            Cells(i, 2) = objResultDiv.innerText
            Cells(i, 3) = objResultDiv.href

            DoEvents
        Next

    End Sub
```

---

**Output**

[image]

HTH
**Santosh**

Comment: Thanks! That works well except after about 100 records I recieve a Run Error 80070005 Access is denied. Any clues on why?

Comment: @CollinHendo Nope, will have to see your data for that. Alternatively you can add 'On error resume next' on top of code. If the solution was helpful pls vote.

Comment: I could provide you a sample of my data. How could I do that?

Comment: Actually the error occurs even if I attempt to use the code on the sample that you provided.Any hints?

Comment: It is a strange error. After running about 100-125 record, I get the access denied and cannot use it in any other workbook or anything.

Comment: Is it possible that my server cuts off access after pulling 100 or so records and then I am on a delay or cut off?

Comment: @CollinHendo  Apologies for late response. You can share the workbook using dropbox or google drive and give me the link. I shall get back to you as feasible to me.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1rj4fqht2I1ws6/Sample.xlsm Thanks! That's just a sample. As you can see, it ended after about 110 records.

Comment: @CollinHendo The link is not working for me. Please make sure you share the link publicly.

Comment: My apologies. I thought it was in my public folder. Here is the correct link https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4qh8vo4g88ulu3/Sample.xlsm

Comment: I too get this error, just about after 60 entries, any resolutions to this please.

Comment: @Vasim I will get back to you on this by tommorow. Can you take a screenshot of issue and give the link.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9u_K1HbgiEKUk5JMlBZdWRzZFE/edit?usp=sharing), it stops at "xmlHttp.send" after sometime (5min or so) it again works - stops after some next 60 entries and so on.....

Comment: @Vasim  I was able to simulate the issue. With lack of time i will try to fix it in weekend. In the meanwhile you may try to add some delay or make async request.

Comment: @Vasim I have updated the code. Give it a try and let me know the response. I tested for about 140 records which ran uninterrupted. Alternatively you may download the sample file from [here](http://goo.gl/VudD5z)

Comment: @Santosh I was trying the get the data of a span tag with class name "_Ex", the code doesn't seem to work. I used the following:

`code`
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyId("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbyTagName("span")(0)
    Set link = objH3.findElementsbyClassName("_Ex") `code`

Comment: Great script. +1. My question is, I have thousands of records. I want to check with google. Can i try without limitation ? If i try to thousands of records, Will google think me that DDOS attack like that ? Is it legit ?

Answer (score 0):

The links seem to be consistently within within H3 tags. Normally you might use something like the following to check until the page has loaded:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal nMilliseconds As Long)

Sub UseIE()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim thePage As Object
    Dim strTextOfPage As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'ie.FullScreen = True
    With ie
        '.Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
        While Not .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE '4
            Sleep 500      'wait 1/2 sec before trying again
        Wend
    End With

    Set thePage = ie.Document
    'more code here
End Sub
```

However, I would, instead, repeatedly try to reference the A element within the first H3 using `getElementsByTagName("H3")`, get the first of these elements, then look within this for the A-link and its href-attribute.

In JavaScript the attempts to reference non-existent elements would return `undefined` but from VBA it will probably need error-handling code.

Once I had obtained the **href** I would stop the navigation (not sure of the command for this, probably `ie.Stop`) or navigate to the next page immediately.

The first link(s) will, however, often be sponsored links and the href returned is a little garbled. The text of these sponsored links appear to include `em` tags. I might use this information to discard these links and look further down the page.

I don't know if there is a better way to do this.