# Control Button to initiate the writing of a new VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

Would it be possible to have a control button (or any mechanism) that once clicked on, a textbox would appear with fields like macro name `Sub "NewMacroTitle"()`, a field for the date, a field for reference sources ("[Getting Links/URL from a webpage-Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976326/)"found this here"), a brief description of what the macro is to do. All of these fields, except Sub "NewMacroTitle"(),  would start with a ' to show a comment and all of this would be inserted into the VBA editor, or enter it into cells on a spreadsheet that could then be copied and pasted into the VBA editor.

My problem is this.  I'm new to VBA.  I'm also the world's worst at documenting macros.  I get an idea for a macro, I'm off into the VBA editor writing away, maybe even get the macro complete.  A week later I'm reviewing the macro and the first thing is "what the heck does this thing do?"

I hope you see what I'm trying to do, essentially some way to force me to document the macro before even starting the actual code.

Comment: Your problem is a common one for any developer i think, and the only way to change that is to face it, and force yourself to document your work. i usually write a short explanation at the start of every macro if any other programmer would look to see, then at each point which i think the code might be not self explenatory i add comments as to what i did there. i ask myself, "if i look at this 1 week from now, would i be 100% what i did?" and if the answer is no, i comment on it. it's habits - and you should adopt them sooner instead of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that will add pre-defined text to the header and/or footer of a sub. I use the one from [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) for error handling code and adding my name and date to the header of each proc. It is worth a look.