# Object doesn´t support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I followed a Tutorial and have an error while executing the code i copied:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim internet As Object
    Dim internetdata As Object
    Dim div_result As Object
    Dim header_links As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim URL As String

    Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = True

    URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+program+in+vba"
    internet.navigate URL

    Do Until internet.readyState >= 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    Set internetdata = internet.document
    Set div_result = internetdata.getElementById("res")


    Set header_links = div_result.getElementsByTagName("h3")

    For Each h In header_links
        Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
        Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
    Next

    MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

The error comes at

```
Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
```

What ist wrong here?

EDIT:
The code should give the URLs out of a google search and write it to excel list:

The code is copied from here:

[Getting Links/URL from a webpage-Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976326/getting-links-url-from-a-webpage-excel-vba)

Comment: The error message tells you that probably `link` is `Nothing` or not a link object and therefore has no `.href`.

Comment: @JNevill `Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)` - it took me a while to find it lol.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! ...The code is 1:1 copied from a tutorial so it should work? ... how can i determine if link is nothing? Or how to try/catch the error if it is nothing?

Comment: Actually this is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You ask X but the problem is Y. • Please [edit] your question (don't use comments) and add more information. What is the goal of your code? What would be the expected outcome? • Also include the link of the tutorial please.

Comment: @PEH: Edited the question! Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Google obviously changed the code of the website since the tutorial was written. This method is not very reliable as everytime Google changes the website it can easily break your code.

Try the following

```
Set div_result = internetdata.getElementById("res")
Set header_links = div_result.getElementsByTagName("a")

Dim h As Variant
For Each h In header_links
    Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = h.href
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the web results without the featured content and video links, you can use below. Also in this code you can control the page number you want to get the links fromby changing the variable pageNo.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim internet As Object
    Dim internetdata As Object
    Dim div_result As Object
    Dim header_links As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Const pageNo = 10  '0 is page 1, 10 is page 2 and so on  0;10;20;30;40

    Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = True

    URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+program+in+vba"
    internet.navigate URL & "&start=" & pageNo

    Do Until internet.readyState >= 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    Set internetdata = internet.document
    Set div_result = internetdata.getElementById("res")
    Set header_links = div_result.getelementsbytagname("h2")

    Dim h As Variant
    For Each div In header_links
        If div.innertext = "Web results" Then
            Set Links = div.ParentElement.getelementsbytagname("a")
            For Each link In Links
                Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
            Next
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but it says "done" but there are no entries in the list!