# Get Google search first result via UDF

Tags: vba, excel

There is a fantastic answer (vba code) by Santosh on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495644/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-in-ie-and-return-the-hyperlink-of-the-first) which search text in Google and captures the first URL result in excel, is there by anyway this can be used/converted as UDF, whereby the formula can be `=Googlefirsturl(A1)` with `A1` having the text which needs to be searched.

Edit: the column 2 data (Name) can be ignored

Comment: just add a button that runs the sub

Comment: Cosmetic change from Sub to Function is a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you really need it as a function then

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Function GoogleFirstUrl(search As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    DoEvents
    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & search & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
    Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)

    GoogleFirstUrl = link.href

End Function
```

Note: *you cannot modify other cells using a UDF so you can return only one thing at a time into the cell you've used to enter the formula into* - I selected the URL as you named your function

Comment: On spot..perfect.......na na na na na na na na ur awesome...(song)

Comment: @mehow, What is the reason for the random number after the search term in your code?

Comment: does google block me for using their browser in automated way ?