# Follow up on UDF for Google first result

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

Following this:
[Get Google search first result via UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213769/get-google-search-first-result-via-udf)

I get the error:
#VALUE!

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Excel 2010 on a Win10

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Google search first result via UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213769/get-google-search-first-result-via-udf)

Comment: Duplicating a duplicated question, this is not the way this site works.