# Web query and excel

Tags: excel, vba, database, excel-web-query

I've a situation here and I'm completely clueless how to go about it.
Say, I have an excel column with a list of companies.

I want to find if the companyA has the product "butter" by looking up the company's website ("companyA.com"). "site:companyA.com "butter" ", this will be the google code to find the product.

If the it has the product "butter" then I should have a yes or Y against the name of the company in the excel as the result.

I also want to know if I can extend the parameters of my search by applying conditions such as date. If the website had the product between 2010 and 2012 or rather say if a web page of company has citation between 2010 and 2012 which contains the product "butter".

It'd be of great help if I could get an idea how to automate the same query for a list of 
companies and get the results, it'll save me a lot of time.

Thanks

Comment: You're basically asking to crawl the website for the word 'Butter' and return a yes if it comes back true? 
Have a look at this: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495644/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-in-ie-and-return-the-hyperlink-of-the-first) I'm sure you'd be able to adopt that somehow to return what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The code in this [link](http://officetricks.com/email-extractor-harvesting-email-addresses/) might be of some use for you. This code crawls the webpage if we give the URL and get the email addresses.

Instead the code can be modified to search for the required word. In this case "Butter".