# Return the top ten Google results hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel, search

I am looking to adapt the code presented by Santosh so that I can return the top ten links, not just the top one result, of a particular Google search.  I need to upload > 1000 search queries and map the results against expected results but I care about more than just the #1 result, I'm looking to see if it returns within the top ten.  I looked into the html and VBA and I can't figure it out.

[Using VBA in Excel to Google Search in IE and return the hyperlink of the first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495644/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-in-ie-and-return-the-hyperlink-of-the-first/17499488#17499488)

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, it looks like this line here is pulling one element in a collection:

```
    Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)
```

So, you're setting the "Link" object to the first object (object 0) in the objH3 collection that has the "a" tag.

What you want to do is loop through that collection. Ex:

```
    Set links = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")
    For i = 0 To 9
      set link = links(i)
      'do stuff
    next
```

Edit:

The loop should be on a higher level of objects:

```
    For i = 0 To 5 
        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(i) 
        Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0) 
        ' Do Stuff 
    Next I
```

Thank you, Richard, for the update.

Comment: Hi, if the answer isn't helpful enough, let me know and I'll update. If it is, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks JMcD!  This looks like the perfect solution but I'm having some trouble getting it to run.  It still goes through the first iteration just fine but when i goes to the second value (1) it errors out - RTE 91; variable not set.  I'm guessing that after 0, values 1-9 are not valid (I did try forcing it to 2 with no luck).  Here is the html for search result 1 & 2 on the webpage but I can't find an identifier to cycle through

Comment: <a href="http://2machines.com/186984/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNGMjdYvSbQjdJiT8mbdHwBIX5oqbQ','h12OsR4Dyp13oulvrwYbEw','0CB4QFjAA','','',event)">The Way I Text Ruined My Dating Life. See If It's Ruining ...</a></h3>

<a href="http://www.shape.com/lifestyle/sex-and-love/10-texting-and-online-dating-tips-tech-savvy-singles" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNFBL_ZFd0l5RmfS8p9qymWqKYIh6A','iU_ctkd57Z1A9ju2cg85wQ','0CCQQFjAB','','',event)">10 Texting and Online Dating Tips for Tech-Savvy ... - Shape</a></h3>

Comment: Got it to work! I had to cycle through at a higher level:
        For i = 0 To 5
            Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(i)
            Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)
            ' Do Stuff
        Next i

Comment: Glad you got it to work! Sorry I didn't see your comments early enough to help out more.

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted. That will give you 5 rep. It's hard getting rep around here when you're first starting off.