# vba code to search google using cell content as search criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, ms-office

firstly I can see that there is a vast amount of questions across multiple websites asking this same question, so please be patient with me as unfortunately the ones I have seen have either not been suitable or don't work and I am far from an expert.

to give you the full scenario - I have an xlsheet with a massive list of unique identifiers for products for the company I work for sells.  I have to (at the moment) manually copy from the sheet to google to see its position in the results.

What would be great is to get a vba code that when I run it (hotkey it), automatically takes the cell contents and sends it into a google search so i effectively reduce my 3 clicks and ctrlV into one hotkey.

Comment: How many rows could the table has? I mean how many phrases would you like to search?

Btw. You could try at least. It seems, that you just want to someone to write the code instead of you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VBA in Excel to Google Search in IE and return the hyperlink of the first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495644/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-in-ie-and-return-the-hyperlink-of-the-first)

Comment: @Srpic it has 10,321, and I only need to search the content of one cell at  a time, they are actually manufacturer codes so i need to search each code individually. And yes.... I want to someone to write the code instead of me, as I am an ignoramus and don't know how to do it, i am simply trying to make a hard job easier :(

Comment: @PEH thanks dude,  I have had a good look at this one, along with many others. I don't need to return hyperlinks, simply click a cell and from there it opens google on my browser with the search results of the content of the cell so it isn't overly suitable, in some ways what I need is actually simpler than what that VBA is doing. Appreciate the thought though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for VBA if all you want to do is open a Google search page one at a time.

With your search phrase in A1, use this formula, for example:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/search?q=" & A1,A1)
```

and fill down as far as required.

That will put a clickable link in column B, corresponding to the search phrase in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
Sub Google_search()

Dim IE As Object

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.navigate ("http://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(1, 1)) 'it will search for value, what is in column A1

  IE.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Arrange the part `Cells(1, 1)` for the cell, what you really want to search.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very kind of you :)