# Continue processing if there is an error searching for page url

Tags: excel, vba, url

I have a list of approximately 20,000 actors to check which has a German Wikipedia page.

I found a code with which you can search for urls via Google and get the first result copied into Excel.
[Using VBA in Excel to Google Search in IE and return the hyperlink of the first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495644/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-in-ie-and-return-the-hyperlink-of-the-first?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I tried to restrict the search to the German Wikipedia by having Google search for German pages only. E.g. "site:de.wikipedia.org intitle:johnny depp"

This works for the known actors.

I get an error when I search for an actor that does not have his own page.

> "Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set"

How can I build a work-around that skips the actor when he/she has no own page and instead continues with the next in the list?

Or maybe you have a simpler solution.

[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VxY0dIpGOLUWUpVoTMCGIZtl9uAot6l_pvvV9fnRlJE)

```vb
Sub XMLHTTP()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String
    
    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.de/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
        Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)

        str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
        str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

        Cells(i, 2) = str_text
        Cells(i, 3) = link.href
        DoEvents
    Next
    
    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time
    
    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `objResultDiv` element is found and if it is found, proceed further else write "Not Found" to the cells.

You may try something like this...

```
Sub XMLHTTP()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim i As Long
Dim str_text As String

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.de/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    If XMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

        If Not objResultDiv Is Nothing Then
            Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
            Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


            str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
            str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

            Cells(i, 2) = str_text
            Cells(i, 3) = link.href
            DoEvents
        Else
            Cells(i, 2) = "Not Found"
            Cells(i, 3) = "Not Found"
        End If
    Else
        Cells(i, 2) = "Not Found"
        Cells(i, 3) = "Not Found"
    End If
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanky for the quick answer. If I try this code, it just gives out "Not Found"  for every actor wheater he has a own page or not. So you have some suggestions?

Comment: I tested it on your file and it worked without an issue. Here is the [File with code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VxY0dIpGOLUWUpVoTMCGIZtl9uAot6l_pvvV9fnRlJE)

Comment: [Here is the file again](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q-Hxelh1wKT_6HuHFegHUyN2uZiOfM9E_JCE2a3zjTw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you very much!! This works out fine for me now! I think the problem yesterday was the google ip restriction after several search inqueries. But I guess there is no easy way around this?

Comment: You may use a counter to count the queries and use `Application.Wait` for 5-10 seconds once the counter reaches say 50 and then reset the counter back to 0 so the next time it reaches 50 again, it will pause again for 5-10 seconds and so on.

Comment: Ok thank you. Another idea I had was to implement a lag of e.g. 0,5sec after each query. But I guess that would be the same concept. Do you an easy way to build this into the existing code? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think you should open a new question with your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard sometimes to scrape information from google using `xmlhttp`, `serverxmlhttp` or `winhttp` request. Even if you try with `proxy`, google can easily detect you as a bot so it will lead you to a `captcha` page and your attempt will be miserably failed. However, the safer approach in this case is to pilot IE. Try the below way instead. if you have IE9 then the `.querySelector()` defined within the scraper will rock.

```
Sub ScrapeGoogle()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim cel As Range, URL$, post As Object

    For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
        URL = "https://www.google.de/search?q=" & Replace(cel.Value, " ", "%20")

        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate URL
            While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set HTML = .document

            If Not HTML.querySelector(".rc h3.r a") Is Nothing Then
                Set post = HTML.querySelector(".rc h3.r a")
                cel(1, 2) = post.innerText
                cel(1, 3) = post.getAttribute("href")
            Else
                cel(1, 2) = "Nothing found"
                cel(1, 3) = "Sorry dear"
            End If
        End With
    Next cel
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it essential to have internet explorer 9 installed to run this code? At the moment I just have Microsoft Edge and I get "runtime error 429: activex component can't create object windows"

Comment: Yep, `IE9` to anything later is required for this script to work otherwise `.querySelector()` won't be supported.