# Return URL From First Search Result

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an Excel workbook of around 25,000 company keywords from which I'd like to get the company website URL.

I am looking to run a VBA script which can run these keywords as a Google search, and pull the URL of the first result into a spreadsheet.

I found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495644/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-in-ie-and-return-the-hyperlink-of-the-first/17499488).
The results of this to be hit-and-miss; some keywords return the URL in the next column, others remain blank.
It also seemed to pull the URL of Google's optimised sub-links in the first search result rather than the main website URL: [Google Search Result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlgmz.png)

I then found the below code [here](https://re-reality.com/technology/web-scrapping-google-search-result-through-vba/) which I ran on a sample list of 1,000 keywords. The author of this blog stipulates that this code works for Mozilla Firefox.

I tested IE code that he has also written but this did not achieve the same results (it was adding hyperlinks consisting of descriptive text from the search results rather than the raw URL).

The Firefox code worked until the 714<sup>th</sup> row, then returned a error message

> "***Run time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set***"

Spreadsheet layout showing successful results and row at which macro stopped
[image]

```vb
Sub GoogleURL ()

    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim objResultDiv As Object
    Dim objH As Object

    lastRow = Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = “https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=” & Cells(i, 1) & “&rnd=” & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject(“MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP”)

        XMLHTTP.Open “GET”, url, False

        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader “Content-Type”, “text/xml”

        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader “User-Agent”, “Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0”

        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject(“htmlfile”)

        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid(“rso”)

        Set objH = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname(“h3”)(0)

        Cells(i, 2).Value = objH.innerText

        Set html = CreateObject(“htmlfile”)

        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid(“rso”)

        Set objH = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname(“cite”)(0)

        Cells(i, 3).Value = objH.innerText

        DoEvents

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any chance that this error could have stemmed from Firefox limiting the number of searches the macro is able to run?

Comment: If you think my suggestion can be the answer to this question then I suggest you accept it as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Firefox is a third party browser for the support scope of Microsoft, I can help you to check the VBA code for the IE browser.

You said that the VBA code given in [this link](https://re-reality.com/technology/web-scrapping-google-search-result-through-vba/) for the IE browser generates the description with the link and your requirement is to store description and link in a separate column.

I tried to modify that sample code as per your requirement.

Here is the modified code from that sample.

```
Option Explicit
Const TargetItemsQty = 1 ' results for each keyword

Sub GWebSearchIECtl()

    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lngFound As Long
    Dim st As String
    Dim colGItems As Object
    Dim varGItem As Variant
    Dim strHLink As String
    Dim strDescr As String
    Dim strNextURL As String

    Set objSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True ' for debug or captcha request cases
    y = 1 ' start searching for the keyword in the first row
    With objSheet
        .Select
        .Range(.Columns("B:B"), .Columns("B:B").End(xlToRight)).Delete ' clear previous results
        .Range(.Columns("C:C"), .Columns("C:C").End(xlToRight)).Delete ' clear previous results
        .Range("A1").Select
        Do Until .Cells(y, 1) = ""
            x = 2 ' start writing results from column B
            .Cells(y, 1).Select
            strSearch = .Cells(y, 1) ' current keyword
            With objIE
                lngFound = 0
                .navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & EncodeUriComponent(strSearch) ' go to first search results page
                Do
                    Do While .Busy Or Not .READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop ' wait IE
                    Do Until .document.READYSTATE = "complete": DoEvents: Loop ' wait document
                    Do While TypeName(.document.getelementbyid("res")) = "Null": DoEvents: Loop ' wait [#res] element
                    Set colGItems = .document.getelementbyid("res").getElementsByClassName("g") ' collection of search result [.g] items
                    For Each varGItem In colGItems ' process each item in collection
                        If varGItem.getelementsbytagname("a").Length > 0 And varGItem.getElementsByClassName("st").Length > 0 Then ' must have hyperlink and description
                            strHLink = varGItem.getelementsbytagname("a")(0).href ' get first hyperlink [a] found in current item
                            strDescr = GetInnerText(varGItem.getElementsByClassName("st")(0).innerHTML) ' get first description [span.st] found in current item
                            lngFound = lngFound + 1
                            'Debug.Print (strHLink)
                            'Debug.Print (strDescr)
                            With objSheet ' put result into cell
                                 .Cells(y, x).Value = strDescr
                                 .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(y, x + 1), strHLink
                                .Cells(y, x).WrapText = True
                                x = x + 1 ' next column
                            End With
                            If lngFound = TargetItemsQty Then Exit Do ' continue with next keyword - necessary quantity of the results for current keyword found
                        End If
                        DoEvents
                    Next
                    If TypeName(.document.getelementbyid("pnnext")) = "Null" Then Exit Do ' continue with next keyword - no [a#pnnext.pn] next page button exists
                    strNextURL = .document.getelementbyid("pnnext").href ' get next page url
                    .navigate strNextURL ' go to next search results page
                Loop
            End With
            y = y + 1 ' next row
        Loop
    End With
    objIE.Quit

    ' google web search page contains the elements:
    ' [div#res] - main search results block
    ' [div.g] - each result item block within [div#res]
    ' [a] - hyperlink ancor(s) within each [div.g]
    ' [span.st] - description(s) within each [div.g]
    ' [a#pnnext.pn] - hyperlink ancor to the next search results page

End Sub

Function EncodeUriComponent(strText As String) As String
    Static objHtmlfile As Object

    If objHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set objHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        objHtmlfile.parentWindow.execScript "function encode(s) {return encodeURIComponent(s)}", "jscript"
    End If
    EncodeUriComponent = objHtmlfile.parentWindow.encode(strText)
End Function

Function GetInnerText(strText As String) As String
    Static objHtmlfile As Object

    If objHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set objHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        objHtmlfile.Open
        objHtmlfile.Write "<body></body>"
    End If
    objHtmlfile.body.innerHTML = strText
    GetInnerText = objHtmlfile.body.innerText
End Function
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

You can try to run it on your side to see the results with large amount of data.

If you meet with any performance issue then I suggest you try it with a smaller amount of data.