# Code is returning the 0 Result instead of First search Link

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been using below code and it returns nothing except `0 results` whereas it should paste the first search result into the Column B.

Any help and solution will be appreciated that why code is not working.

**Data in column A**

```
3P Pty Limited
BakPhysio
BD Rowa
BHC's Can View
Blooms The Chemist
5Odyassist Health And Wellness
Care Pharmaceuticals
```

Code

```
Sub XMLHTTP_Count()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText

    If html.getElementById("resultStats") Is Nothing Then
        str_text = "0 Results"
    Else
        str_text = html.getElementById("resultStats").innerText
    End If
        Cells(i, 2) = str_text
        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure that the code that you give in StackOverflow compiles. This is important.

Comment: This is potentially a duplicate question, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60653046/return-url-from-first-search-result?rq=1) and adept to your need. You can't really use xmlhttp to get google search result.

Comment: I have tried this code before it just opens the first values search result in `Internet Explorer` and does nothing. Window remains open and when i close the `Internet Explorer`  windows that error appears https://imgur.com/OSBHIjP on the line `Do While TypeName(.document.getElementById("res")) = "Null":` @Raymond Wu

Answer (score 1):

1. Google is not just a normal website, it has quite nice protection vs unwanted web-crawling.
2. Try to debug as much as you can, and see what `html.body.innerHTML` returns.
3. If you have done it you would have understood the reason of point 1.

Take a look at the code below. It prints the data of `html.body.innerHTML` and writes it in the third column. Furthermore, it provides you with the first `<LI>` of the `html.body.innerhtml` of the response from google.

```
Sub XmlHttpCount()
    
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim someText As String
    Dim url As String
    
    For i = 1 To 7
        url = "https://google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)

        Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        xmlHttp.Open "GET", url, False
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        xmlHttp.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerhtml = xmlHttp.responseText
        
        Debug.Print html.body.innerhtml
        Cells(i, 3) = html.body.innerhtml
        
        
    If html.GetElementsByTagName("LI") Is Nothing Then
        someText = "0 Results"
    Else
        someText = html.GetElementsByTagName("LI")(0).InnerText
    End If
        Cells(i, 2) = someText
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "END"
    
End Sub
```

If you want to do something that actually works, then try to include the browser object and wait some seconds before trying the next loop, google may respond better.

Comment: I appreciate you answer @Vityata and you define it very well. But what i want is here https://imgur.com/LPA6UqA I just want the First Search Result `Link` in `column B` I have been struggling since a week but could not make it correct. I would appreciate if you could create a solution for this as well. I am just beginner to VBA not an expert to make these changes. I would greatly appreciate the help. @Vityata